# In the United States is doing business in only some states considered discrimination?

Tags: united-states, ccpa

A business would like to only operate in states except for California to avoid the $7500-per-person fine CCPA demands. Is it legal or would the business have to leave out the whole of USA?

For information on the CCPA, see: https://oag.ca.gov/privacy/ccpa

Comment: I'm not the one that downvoted you (this is mostly fine except that "bussinessd" is not a a word, which I've now fixed), but you've been posting a rapid-fire series of questions with serious quality issues (_please_ use your browser's spell check feature!) and I imagine people are tired of cleaning them up.  You've also been deleting and reposting them rather than fixing the originals.  Again, not the case here, but I could see folks being grouchy about seeing a bunch of these.

Comment: Ok I will check spellings and grammar next time.

Comment: It's a TV Trope: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OfferVoidInNebraska

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### I have a really good pizza place near my home but the bastards won't deliver when I go interstate! Now, that's discrimination!

Yes, it's discrimination. However, it's not unlawful discrimination.

Discrimination is not unlawful unless it is on the basis of a [protected class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_group). Geography isn't a protected class of itself. It can be if it's used as a proxy for a protected class, such as excluding certain neighbourhoods which correspond with racial or religious groups, but that's not the case here.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116032/discussion-on-answer-by-dale-m-in-the-united-states-is-doing-business-in-only-so).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly legal to exclude places from your delivery service - even if you only do so for certain goods. For example, you can't deliver glues containing certain chemicals in some areas, or cans that are larger than a certain size. As a result, [McMaster-Carr does not deliver contact cement to certain Areas and States](https://www.mcmaster.com/glue/contact-adhesives/). Sure, it's discrimination, but totally legal.

So, because that law might prevent you from doing things as you do them, you can opt to not do business in that area - just like Project Gutenberg blocks Germans, because they don't want to do business in Germany after a lawsuit.